# How can I get the password with which gmail is logged in on iPhone, when the password in the Keychain doesn't work on browser?

Tags: iphone, keychain, jailbreak

Around 2.5 years ago, I lost access to my primary google account. Not sure I forgot password or it got compromised. But a curious thing has happened since I've not given up trying to recover that account. The gmail and youtube remained logged in on my iPhone 5S. When it became impossible to keep using the iPhone without updating 2 years ago, I reluctantly updated, even had to reset due to error, but to my amazement, the google account logged in automatically after reinstalling the apps, implying that the password was within iPhone or iCloud. And YouTube logs in afresh every time I start it, till this date, so there's that.

I took help of internet and found that password for this account was there and visible in settings app. It was an old password, which I had already changed months before I lost access. I tried logging in using that password on browser and of course it didn't work. It's the same password in Keychain. So, this means that these apps are using a different password than what is being shown in settings and keychain.

Is there a way I can get this password from my iPhone (iOS 12.5.5), even if it requires jailbreaking? Why does keychain have wrong password and yet there is some other source from where iPhone is pulling passwords even today which even survived the reset? Please feel free to suggest any wild ideas you might have to get this password, I'm willing to go to any lengths and will be grateful till death.

Comment: Obviously it isn't actually yours, otherwise you'd just go through password recovery on Gmail.  You could just say that up front.

Comment: Hey kind stranger on the internet, do you happen to know the answers to the above questions?